# can xmpp on google app engine push message to javascript client

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, channel-api

I am creating a website on google app engine and I want to allow users to chat with each other just like gmail.I have read that there are 2 options - xmpp and channel api.

Now I want to know,can the xmpp sever on gae talk to javascript clients and push messages to browser's javascript just like channel api.everyhere I see that xmpp on gae can talk to xmpp clients,but I did not find info on talking to javascript clients.I would prefer to use xmpp as it gives more features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use XMPP to talk to Javascript clients, you could use [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) -- however you'll need an XMPP account of some sort for the client to sign into.

Comment: along with this post - stackoverflow.com/questions/11802330/app-engine-chat-application your answer answers my question